# Python tkinter how can I copy information from a Text widget to a Canvas widget?

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, text, widget

To put it simple, i want to write stuff in the text widget and then have it copied onto a canvas widget on the same coordinates (in the code below the Text widget size is the same as the canvas one)

[here is an image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1zQ7.png)

**Here is the written code:**

```
from tkinter import *

#root configuration
root = Tk()
root.config(bg='black')

#function that "replaces" text with canvas
def replace_TextWidget_with_CanvasWidget():
    global text_editor
    global written_text

    #gets text from the text widget and destroys it
    written_text = text_editor.get('0.0', '100.0')
    text_editor.destroy()

    #i want the copied text from the text widget to be inserted on the canvas
    text_editor = Canvas(root, height=851, width=601, bg='white')
    text_editor.pack()
    text_editor.insert()

#button
button = Button(root, command=replace_TextWidget_with_CanvasWidget)
button.pack()

#initial text widget
text_editor = Text(root, height=50, width=75)
text_editor.pack()
text_editor.insert('1.0', 'HERE I WRITE SOMETHING I WANT TO BE COPIED ON THE CANVAS LATER')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the `Canvas` widget? The method for creating text items is documented. By the way, the first index of the text widget is `"1.0"`, not `"0.0"`.

Comment: You should get the font used in the text widget as well because most likely the fonts used in text widget and canvas are different.

Comment: where do you have `canvas.create_text(...)` to put text on canvas? See [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm). You can't uses `canvas.insert(text_id, ...)` if you didn't use `text_id = canvas.create_text(...)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to show some text to display only. If that's the case, set it's `state` property to disabled **after** updating it.

`text_editor.configure(state='disabled')`

However, if you really want to replace it with a canvas with the same information, here is your modified code. Please note that canvas widget doesn't have any insert method. Instead, it has a `create_text(x,y,text='my text')` method.

```py
from tkinter import * #Not a good programming approach, use import tkinter as tk instead

#function that "replaces" text with canvas
def replace_TextWidget_with_CanvasWidget():
    global text_editor

    #gets text from the text widget and destroys it
    written_text = text_editor.get('0.0', '100.0')
    text_editor.destroy()

    #i want the copied text from the text widget to be inserted on the canvas
    new_canvas = Canvas(root, height=200, width=400, bg='white')
    new_canvas.pack()
    root.update() #Necessary if you want to get the current coordinates of the canvas
    # print(new_canvas.winfo_x(),new_canvas.winfo_y()) #print canvas x,y pos
    new_canvas.create_text(new_canvas.winfo_x()+200,new_canvas.winfo_y(), text=written_text) #Create text at x,y coords

#root configuration
root = Tk()
root.config(bg='black')

#button
button = Button(root, width=10, height=2, text="OK", command=replace_TextWidget_with_CanvasWidget)
button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

#initial text widget
text_editor = Text(root, height=10, width=50)
text_editor.pack()
text_editor.insert('1.0', 'HERE I WRITE SOMETHING I WANT TO BE COPIED ON THE CANVAS LATER')

root.mainloop()
```

You may have trouble positioning the text at the correct x,y co-ordinates and with text wrapping. If you want text wrapping, `create_text` has a width property. You can specify it to a specific dimension like `width=100`

Answer (score 0):

To add text to Canvas

```
text_id = text_editor.create_text(0, 0, text=written_text, anchor='nw')
```

---

```
# from tkinter import * # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def replace_TextWidget_with_CanvasWidget():
    global text_editor
    global written_text

    written_text = text_editor.get('1.0', 'end')
    text_editor.destroy()

    text_editor = tk.Canvas(root, height=851, width=601, bg='white')
    text_editor.pack()
    text_id = text_editor.create_text(0, 0, text=written_text, anchor='nw')
    #text_editor.insert(text_id, 'end', written_text)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.config(bg='black')

button = tk.Button(root, text="OK", command=replace_TextWidget_with_CanvasWidget)
button.pack()

text_editor = tk.Text(root, height=50, width=75)
text_editor.pack()
text_editor.insert('1.0', 'HERE I WRITE SOMETHING I WANT TO BE COPIED ON THE CANVAS LATER')

root.mainloop()
```